# spring-boot:RSA premaster secret error: SunTls12RsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available

Tags: spring-boot, maven-plugin, maven-jetty-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am running A spring-boot application started by jetty. I used to start succeesfully. but now something was just wrong, very strange.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tsinghua.geoservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>geo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>geoservice</name>
    <description>geo service</description>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mvn-repo</id>
            <url>http://maven.nlpcn.org/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ansj</groupId>
            <artifactId>ansj_seg</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>-->
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-staticdocs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
            <!--<version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.35</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- sesame -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
            <artifactId>sesame-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
            <artifactId>sesame-sail-nativerdf</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

And here are the logs:

```
➜  /Users/myname/Documents/Coding/IdeaProjects/Spring/GeoAPI>mvn spring-boot:run
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building geoservice 1.0
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ geo >>>
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ geo ---
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0.6/maven-plugin-api-2.0.6.jar
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-profile/2.0.6/maven-profile-2.0.6.jar
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-registry/2.0.6/maven-plugin-registry-2.0.6.jar
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0.6/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.6.jar
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0.6/maven-project-2.0.6.jar
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-core/2.0.6/maven-core-2.0.6.jar
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter/2.0.6/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter-2.0.6.jar
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.0.6/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.6.jar
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-error-diagnostics/2.0.6/maven-error-diagnostics-2.0.6.jar
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-descriptor/2.0.6/maven-plugin-descriptor-2.0.6.jar
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0.6/maven-artifact-2.0.6.jar
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.0.6/maven-settings-2.0.6.jar
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-model/2.0.6/maven-model-2.0.6.jar
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-monitor/2.0.6/maven-monitor-2.0.6.jar
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 3.605 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-20T13:37:29+08:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 18M/220M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project geo: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): RSA premaster secret error: SunTls12RsaPremasterSecret KeyGenerator not available -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Thank you. Any comment or answer will help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven with Eclipse:

1-
[image]

2-

[image]

Source: https://www.codetd.com/en/article/9438315

Answer (score 0):

These error seems to be related to JDK updates. Check if it has been reinstalled in the server that raises the error, and eventually restore your old version.

Answer (score 0):

I had met the same situation like yours with Eclipse.
It seems that maven can not download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-monitor/2.0.6/maven-monitor-2.0.6.jar from the website ,you can download it and put into your maven repository,then build again.If the same situation come to another jar or pom , use maven command line to build your project.

Answer (score 0):

I'd had a similar error in my project.
It was possible to load the .jar from artifactory using the url, but the problem still occurred in the command line and IDE. This happened after I changed the JAVA_HOME.

Killing all running gradle processes with the `kill -9 PID` helped me solve this problem.